# Creating barchart using the data stored in the Viewbag

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I will like to create a barchart from the data I stored in the `Viewbag`. I have the code for the Controller. The data is from Sql Server. I believe the barchart plot code will be written in the View (using JavaScript, Html, CSS).

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetRimCalcs()
{
    //List<RimCalc> listOfCategggories = null;
    Connectors aConn = Connectors.GetInstance();
    var lisy = aConn.GetRimCalc();
    var date = lisy.Select(x =>x.Date);
    var netprofit = lisy.Select(x => x.Rprofit);

    ViewBag.ListOfCategories = lisy;
    ViewBag.dates = date;
    ViewBag.nprofit = netprofit;

    return View();
}
```

**View**

Needs help to create the barchart using the `ViewBags`

Comment: Not sure what advantage ViewBag is here? I would just build up a model and pass it to the View. In terms of rendering the chart what have you tried? I have used high charts. The data can be json dump using an mvc controller or API using a Web Api controller.

Comment: you want to create bar chart using pure javascript?

Comment: Yes. Basically I am thinking looping through the data to plot the chart using JavaScript will work, but I just don't how. Thanks